# Select objects from a collection with same property values

Tags: c#, collections

Is there an easy way to select the members with same currencyId's so I can sum them with each other, or do I need to do else if for every currencyId there is ?

```
if(model.CurrencyId == -1)
        {
            resultModel.Add(new ReportModel
            {
                AccountName = "Sum",
                BalanceSum = resultModel.Where(q => q.CurrencyId == 1).Sum(q => q.Balance)

            });
        }
        else
        {
            resultModel.Add(new ReportModel
            {
                AccountName = "Sum",
                BalanceSum = resultModel.Sum(q => q.Balance)

            });
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have `if(model.CurrencyId == -1)` and then `.Where(q => q.CurrencyId == 1).`? Is -1 and 1 a typo? Also whats your expected output?

Comment: Sounds like you want `resultModel.GroupBy(q => q.CurrencyId)`

Comment: @Greg its not a typo, ``` model.CurrencyId == -1 ``` is a completely irreleveant control, I just want to select the objects within the collection that have the same CurrencyId's and sum them with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sum of the balance for each currency, you can preform `groupBy`, followed by `select` & `sum`.

E.g:

```
var balanceSum = t.GroupBy(q => q.CurrencyId)
    .Select(q => q.Sum(x => x.Balance));
```

To add it to the resultModel, you can do something like:

```
var reportData = t.GroupBy(q => q.CurrencyId)
    .Select(q => new ReportModel()
    {
        AccountName = "Sum",
        BalanceSum = q.Sum(x => x.Balance)
    });

resultModel.AddRange(reportData);
```

*If the data is only assigned to resultModel once, then you can probably replace AddRange with equals.*